# Difference between regression between groups vs across all subjects (continuum)?

Tags: regression, group-differences

I'd like to understand this better in terms of drawbacks and suitability.

For example, if my data includes investigating differences between 2 patient groups and a control group (3 groups in total), how can I tell which is a more appropriate method to use and maybe, adding strength to the model?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to supply some more information about your data. Is it a case-control design with controls matched to the patients or are they simply different groups? What is the difference between the two patient groups? Do you want to compare both patient groups to the controls, or do you also want to compare the patient groups with each other? What is the outcome variable of interest? Are there any other variables that need to be included in the analysis? Are the variables measured at one occasion or are there repeated measures?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have further clarified below:

The controls are matched to the patient groups in age and gender, but not any other variables. The difference between the patient groups is they are both of different disorder subtypes. I would like to compare all three groups. There are no repeated measures. The DV is a neuroimaging metric (e.g. volume of subcortical brain areas). There may be 1 or 2 other covariates.

Does this help in identifying which method may be more suitable, or how I may go about finding which is more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on this one, so I hope somebody else can join in the discussion.

One option is to do a standard linear regression with indicator variables for patient groups (i.e. x1 is a binary variable with 1 meaning patient group 1 and 0 meaning patient group 2 or control and x2 is a binary variable with 1 meaning patient group 2 and 0 meaning patient group 1 or control) and the other covariates as you please. You will then compare both patient groups to the controls but you will not compare the patient groups with each other. You can do this by changing indicator variable x1 for another, we can call it x3, which is constructed so that 1 means control and 0 means patient groups 1 or 2. However, the drawback of this model is that you do not take the matching in account, and that's where I'm not sure.

Since you did the matching only by age and gender, including these variables (and possibly their interaction term) should be enough, provided the assumption of a linear relationship between age and the DV holds (if there is a relationship). If not, you need to add a non-linear variable.

Anyway, I'm not sure this is the best way to handle the case-control design. Perhaps a linear mixed model could be used, so that each patient and its control(s) will share the same level in a factor variable and this factor acts as a random intercept, but I'm not sure this would be appropriate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The need for handling the matching presents problems as there is no principled unique way to go.  From the extremely brief description of the problem it appears to be an optimal situation for **not** matching, because the matching can be be replaced with simple covariate adjustment.  And if the matching algorithm discarded any subjects it’s invalid.